# Labeling and referencing subsequent equations after adding a new equation before them

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, labels, update

I have a finished document with labeled equations and their respective references.
If I update this document by adding a new equation in the middle of the text, would there be a way of both labels and references of the subsequent equations to be automatically updated?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Of course. You only need to car for unique equation labels and in references use correct labels.

Comment: Please tell us *how* you've labelled equations. E.g., have you used `\label` instructions? And, which command(s) have you employed to create cross-references to the labeled equations? Please be specific.

Comment: equations in latex are automatically numbered by default so the numbering should just work automatically. there is no need to change the `\label` that is the whole reason for using `\label` and `\ref` that you can add and remove equations and have the numbers be re-calculated.

Comment: Hi Mico, indeed I was misusing the \label option; I was not using the colon between eq and number; for example \label{eq1}. Thanks a lot for you, Zarko and David.

Comment: there is nothing special about colon, but it is best not to use numbers in the label as it confuses you if the equation with numer 3 has \label{2}

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification David!

Comment: Please consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 4):

The reason that LaTeX has `\label` and `\ref` is for the case that you describe. There is no need to change the label keys, the numbering and cross referencing will automatically adjust as equations are added or removed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

See Equation (\ref{eq:xy}).

An equation
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:defx}
  x=2
\end{equation}

Some text.

Another equation
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:xy}
  x=y
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The first sentence typesets as "See Equation (2)"

[image]

Now if the document is edited, inserting a new equation

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

See Equation (\ref{eq:xy}).

An equation
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:defx}
  x=2
\end{equation}

Insert this equation
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:oops}
  1=0
\end{equation}

Some text.

Another equation
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:xy}
  x=y
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Then after running LaTeX a couple of times the first line will automatically adjust to "See Equation (3)"

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much David!